# Como fazer este layout em Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.portable

Qual estrutura devo usar pra fazer esse layout?
É um `listView` ou `gridView`, não sei como fazer esta parte do **SOM**,
quando coloco o `listView`, aparece só alinha de baixo, a de cima não!

[image: Como fazer essas linhas no SOM]

Comment: Você precisa utilizar uma ListView para este layout. Não deu certo?

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer utilizando StackLayout

De uma olhadinha nesse link :

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout?view=xamarin-forms

Você vai empilhando os componentes na tela, e se os componentes ultrapassarem o tamanho vertical da tela, você pode colocar todos eles em um ScrollView.

A respeito das opções/botões você pode fazer utilizando o TapGestureRecognizer,

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap

Answer (score 0):

Abaixo eu escrevi o código para você utilizar.
Se vc quiser utilizar para as 4 opções, basta você colocar quatro vezes este código dentro de um ScrollView (opcional).

```
<Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> <!-- Bloco 1 -->
          <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/> <!-- Bloco 2 -->                               
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
          <Label Text="Som"/>
      </StackLayout>
      <!-- Stack com palavra e ícone -->
      <StackLayout Grid.Column="1"
                   HorizontalOptions="End"
                   Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Label Text="Ring"/>
           <Image Source="sua_imagem"
                  HeightRequest="20"/>
       </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Se a parte do "Ring" não ficar exatamente no final da tela (horizontalmente) basta você ir ajustando o Width do bloco 2.

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que seja utilizando o TableView do Xamarin Forms

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview